# Horizontal Slide/Toggle of divs.. layout issue..Help needed

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to accomplish the following:
I have a main Div(A) in the center of my page and 1 div (menus) on either side of Div(A) that would toggle on the click of a button. I'm using jQuery to horizontally slide the side divs/menus. This is the jQuery code (credit to [Karl Swedberg](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#trigger1').click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $("#B");
    $marginLefty.animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? -$marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
    }, 1500, 'swing');
  });

  $('#trigger2').click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $("#C");
    $marginLefty.animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
    }, 1500, 'swing');
  });
});
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is that when one of the side Divs/menu is open , the width of Div(A) would decrease (so that all 'visible' divs are aligned) but would add a horizontal scrollbar inside of it. The same applies when both menus are open. 
Something like [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/horizontaltoggle.jpg).

I can't seem to figure out how to make Div(A) to adjust it's width so that a scrollbar appears when the a menu is open, but the scrollbar disapears and Div(A) takes it's original width when the menu(s) is/are closed..

Anybody can help me with the CSS part to properly layout this so i can achieve this functionality?

Comment: May I suggest http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HTML5 data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to mark whether the sidebar is collapsed or not, and set the width every time #trigger1 or #trigger 2 is clicked. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QdrK/25/). Does that help?

```
function adjustSize(side) {

    // Vars
    var fullWidth = 200;
    var sideWidth = 50;
    var obj = $('.'+side);

    // Get the jQuery object of the side and handle collapsing here
    if (obj.attr('data-expanded') == "1") {
        obj.css({'float':'none','clear':'both'});
        obj.attr('data-expanded',0);
    } else {
        obj.css({'float':'left','clear':'none'});
        obj.attr('data-expanded',1);
    }

    // Create a filteredWidth
    var filteredWidth = fullWidth;
    $('div[data-expanded=1]').each(function() { filteredWidth = filteredWidth - sideWidth; });

    // Apply filteredWidth
    $('.b').width(filteredWidth);
    $('span').text('I am now: '+filteredWidth);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that..actually the Div(A) acts like a canvas with a predefined width (dynamically allocated). For instance,assuming my page width is 1200px, and the side menus are 200px each (fixed) with one aligned on the left and one on the right, then if the canvas width is 500px then it should be centered in the middle of the page with no problem. But if the canvas width > (1200px - 400px) then it should be 800px with an internal horizontal scrollbar..